# Converting between instances of a class template using a member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I have a couple of strong types that are just aliases of a class template that contains useful shared code.

```
template <typename T>
struct DiscretePosition {
public:
    int x{0};
    int y{0};
    
    // ... useful generic functions
};

struct ChunkTag{};
struct TileTag{};

using ChunkPosition = DiscretePosition<ChunkTag>;
using TilePosition = DiscretePosition<TileTag>;
```

I would like to write a constructor or helper function to help me convert one of these types to the other.

```
TilePosition tilePosition{1, 1};

ChunkPosition chunkPosition{tilePosition};
// or
ChunkPosition chunkPosition{tilePosition.asChunkPosition()};
```

This constructor would just take the underlying `x`, `y` and scale them to match the other type using a constant.

Is there a way to do this, or would I need to use a free function?

Comment: You can simply add a constructor template in `DiscretePosition` taking other `DiscretePosition`s. Have you tried that and if you did, what went wrong?

Comment: Maybe my syntax is just wrong then, but I tried to make a constructor that took `const DiscretePosition<TileTag>&` and got ```error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct AM::DiscretePosition<T>'```

Edit: Oh, maybe I'm not clear. The values of `TilePosition` and `ChunkPosition` aren't the same, there's a scaling factor between them. I want a constructor for these types specifically, as opposed to a generic one that takes `const DiscretePosition<T>&`.

Comment: C++20, sorry, just added the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possible generic solution that allows you to specialize a `get_scaling_factor` function for conversions you want to allow:

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAGxcpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgZgCspAAOqAqETgwe3r4BQemZjgJhEdEscQnJtpj2JQxCBEzEBLk%2BfoG19dlNLQRlUbHxiSkKza3t%2BV3j/YMVVaMAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzhyN5YANQmO25O48SYrKfYJhoAgvcPl14OR24IXgwA1gAqTGAJgA7FZgQARU5WR6vd5/OiYAFA0EgyE7aFPR4ETAsVIGbGnNwEACeqUYrEwRz%2BpCOJLJzDYRzkt2eaAY40wADcxEd0GsYvQjsBMAQAPoKUS0cLAUVUJgOEgQJZQ57PbG4/GYQksx5sjnc2i8/mC4ViiViaWy%2BVEYiEz7ff6Amnw%2BhI25Kk4ox5HH1HK4EdYMI5mFWPVGqrE4vFMbEnM508mMv46l4EYhvAhHcF4CX%2BlQZLICT0Y1JeAV4ZAgZ6%2Bo7hTOqEEWDTh9HV311o7ExvNiGhh41ts%2BgD0Q6OADoJ0cvEoqF5DcKIsQK0dZwwHNkFBH%2B77s7mRfnitkIB3VDSO8SlkcQEdVBBVCtOxAL8Xw2Hvb71dGCfHSYnKcydjud8fUwVQ8QrQgsxzZA82UAsGggPVM13GD9zgw8BEJF1EUBFkzH8I5UAIBB4mVYCrxvCAiJI4gx1UI4ACohRFcVJUtOUFVtM5qSZd0ljI7cfRpYkqOI%2BIx2JRjmLNNijCtTisJpADsCVASBxRXsw17Vs3weadpQ%2BL5fnQwsg1OcEoL3bETIaO0jMdIFAL7fSjCpBEbOyOMLJQ2D4OyLCETdJydMxB4OxYJhwg9RtBzc%2BgPKLRx4r8zDQSCI4uBbDFYvtYyUqDZB7IShhGySg9TKy2LxnQEAUDWTNtTOI5CodYq6LjNxCROMwzBpcwzA6rqWryjCGAkwamuq2rXFoPsaxHQjbXIhbcp%2BYrmqK/LSvc/KxyYBRVuKpVKt01EOBWWhOCSXg/A4LRSFQThOssawjgUNYNkpXYeFIAhNHOlYfhAJINH0ThJBu/6Hs4XgFBAUG/ru87SDgWAkHq0sCHISg0FxBEEiCTB8BtPR%2BEEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUJHfquLYfoAd2IJhUk4HgLquyHGcejgAHkvAITHCKoG8AA5/AAWn8SRmoMVyuB2McNHVo4IA8PH6GIbqdi4JZeERrQVggJBcdSfHscQ1BdZGA5DGAVWNFBmhaGxYg4YgGIoZicIWmJbneFxthBCFhhaGDxmsAioxxFjvArnXTlMDhxnQMwZBRa2e66zqKGpRiDniGJDwsChtM8BYEOVioAxgAUAA1PBMFZoX6RDmnhElKnpDJ%2BQlDUKHdCCZXjGsax9DwGI4cgFZUFSBoM9l6rzNMF7LDMe67GzhoXAYdxPA6PRQnCIZKhGQp8qmPwb9G%2BZhgJ7p996CY2hP/Igj39cBD6VoT8r4v1mJML%2B99bAfyAYsI2qx1ibD0GmTALNkaXQ4NdUgt17qC1UDLeWisnYqzVhrDQWtnpWEsDSXAhASAG3Sjra2es6HG1%2Bv9fipAgYgzBhwCGmCoaC1hvDVhSN2FoLMPzbBMNhFmxWGnb22QQCSCAA%3D%3D)

```
#include <iostream>

struct ChunkTag{};
struct TileTag{};

template<typename T, typename U>
consteval double get_scaling_factor();

template<>
consteval double get_scaling_factor<ChunkTag, TileTag>() {
    return 2;
}

template <typename T>
struct DiscretePosition {
public:
    int x{0};
    int y{0};
    
    // ... useful generic functions

    DiscretePosition(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    template<typename U>
    explicit DiscretePosition(const DiscretePosition<U>& other)
    : x(other.x * get_scaling_factor<T, U>())
    , y(other.y * get_scaling_factor<T, U>())
    {}
};

using ChunkPosition = DiscretePosition<ChunkTag>;
using TilePosition = DiscretePosition<TileTag>;

int main() {
    TilePosition tilePosition{1, 1};

    ChunkPosition chunkPosition{tilePosition};
    std::cout << chunkPosition.x << ", " << chunkPosition.y << std::endl;
    // or
    // ChunkPosition chunkPosition{tilePosition.asChunkPosition()};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer worked fine, but I ended up doing something different as a more general-purpose solution.

For each strong type that I wanted to add functionality to, I turned it into a full derived class:

```
class ChunkPosition : public DiscretePosition<DiscreteImpl::ChunkTag>
{
public:
    ChunkPosition();

    ChunkPosition(int inX, int inY);

    explicit ChunkPosition(const TilePosition& tilePosition);
};

class TilePosition : public DiscretePosition<DiscreteImpl::TileTag>
{
public:
    TilePosition();

    TilePosition(int inX, int inY);

    explicit TilePosition(const ChunkPosition& chunkPosition);
};
```